# How to conditionally compile `InternalsVisibleTo(...)` assembly info?

Tags: c#, .net-core, preprocessor-directive, assemblyinfo

Using .Net Core 2.1, my AssemblyInfo.cs looks like this:

using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;

```
[assembly: InternalsVisibleTo("RazorWare.Core.Media")]
[assembly: InternalsVisibleTo("RazorWare.Core.Business")]

#if DEBUG
[assembly: InternalsVisibleTo("RazorWare.CoreDL.Testing")]
[assembly: InternalsVisibleTo("RazorWare.CoreDL.Testing.CreateNativeWindow")]
[assembly: InternalsVisibleTo("RazorWare.CoreDL.Testing.CreateEventPump")]
#endif
```

...and a screenshot of relevant project properties:
[image]

The assembly attributes surrounded by `#if-#endif` are not grayed out when the project is set to `Release`. How can I coerce the compiler (VS???) to recognize the `#if-#endif` directive?

Comment: "Define DEBUG constant" (eg. DEBUG conditional symbol) *is shown checked* - is that.. desired?

Comment: Actually just found a question that suggests unchecking "Define DEBUG constant". However, the properties page will not let me uncheck.

Comment: Well that Tick is the problem, since it is defining the thing the `#if` is checking for. Hmmm.... Does your project file import from any of your own '.targets' files?

Comment: Do you use ReSharper? If so, it's a bug in the ReSharper engine which I've experienced with projects using the new project format. The conditional symbols work, , ReSharper just has issues displaying it properly. Notice also your conditional symbols seem to repeat each other. *That* is a bug with visual studio. I had to fix that by manually editing the project file and then *never* using the property screens to edit those values. It seems to only be an issue (in both cases) when the project is mulitargeted.

Comment: As it turns out there is a bug in VS. If I unload and reload the project, the IDE shades out the code and the compiler obeys the directive. https://github.com/dotnet/project-system/issues/2733

The link also describes the bug @pinkfloydx33 raises.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can't untick DEBUG, then use your own symbol, e.g. `INTERNALS_VISIBLE_TO_TESTING`.  Define that in just the RELEASE configuration.

However, I personally wouldn't bother with any of this: I'd include the `InternalsVisibleTo` attribute in both configurations. It does no harm to have it in the release configuration, and it has a distinct benefit: it means you can test the actual binary that you're going to release.

Comment: One reason against exposing internals in a Release build with an unsigned assembly is that it means a third party can write code to access your internals simply by naming their assembly using a name from one of these attributes, which can be seen by reflecting the assembly. This isn't an issue for signed assemblies.

Comment: @Richardissimo: As opposed to disassembling to IL, adding the attribute themselves and reassembling? If someone wants to do it, they can do so pretty easily either way. (Or just use reflection...)